# How to remove automatically created container in GCP AutoPilot Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created an auto pilot cluster in GCP.

I see the following container that is running all the time.

```
gmp-operator    Deployment  1/1     gke-gmp-system
```

And I am not able to delete/remove it. What is that? Does it cost money?

When I try to delete it, I get the following error:

```
You don't have permissions to update the resource.
```

### Addendum

I deleted the cluster, and then created a new auto pilot clutser. I just gave it a name and then created; that is it. I still see the gmp-operator container running. When I go to logs, I see a bunch of errors as following (I only copy part of it):

```
TLS handshake error from 45.19.177.33:33366: EOF
{error: validatingwebhookconfigurations.admissionregistration.k8s.io "gmp-operator.gmp-system.monitoring.googleapis.com" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gke-gmp-system:operator" cannot get resource "validatingwebhookconfigurations" in API group "admissionregistration.k8s.io" at the cluster…
```

It does not tell me anything sensible. What is going on?

### Addendum 2

I had deleted the cluster. But after reading Gari Singh's answer, I created it again. But I now see even more things going there..

[image]

I had 1 pod running before. Now I have 4 in the list.

- Where do they come from?
- What is the concrete command that I can use to get rid of them?
- Is it recommended to have them? If yes, why?
- Does any of these pods cost money?

I created another AutoPilot cluster for some time ago in another project and I do not have these things running in that one. Now I am working on a new project and I start seeing these pods when I create a new cluster exactly in the same way as I did before.

Comment: You may also read this [No Privilege Pods](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#no_privileged_pods), Once Your Setup Is Configure For Autopilot, Its Managed By Google. Try using the Standard cluster configuration if you wish to modify your setup.

Comment: @JeffreyD. Thanks for your answer and the link. But I still could not make it clear to me what the hack this container is doing. It is absolutely not me who created it. It came from nowhere.

Comment: this is a good reference link to understand [Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#what-is-autopilot).

Comment: I can't see anywhere in the docs where this auto created container is coming from. My major problem is NOT that I am not able to delete it. The major issue is why it is there at all. I haven't created it for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Autopilot clusters automatically enable managed collection for Managed Service for Prometheus.  (On GKE Standard it can be optionally enabled via a flag: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--enable-managed-prometheus.

While you can see the deployment in Autopilot, you are actually not charged for those pods.

If you want to disable it, you should be able to update your cluster via gcloud and pass the https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update#--disable-managed-prometheus flag.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. What is the purpose of this pod then? Is it recommended to keep it? What are the pros and cons of having that pod there? It is ok that it exists there as long as it will never cost me additional money and it brings a value.

Comment: I added more information under ADDENDUM 2 in my question. Any chance you can have a look at it?

Comment: @edn  - just so I can test something on my side, which release channel and version is your cluster running?

Comment: Release channel: Regular channel. Version: 1.23.8-gke.1900. I don't know how to steer the version if I need to change it. I just create an AutoPilot cluster and do not change/modify anything else other than giving it a name.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you would like to know what is the reason that the “gmp-system” namespace appeared inside your GKE Workspace.

I have noticed that you are using the Managed Service for Prometheus. Inside your logs, you can find the resource where it is pulling data from [1] core/v1/namespaces/gmp-system/services/gmp-operator, which is needed for Prometheus to work.

Google Cloud Managed Service for Prometheus is Google Cloud's fully managed multi-cloud solution for Prometheus metrics and data collection [2](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus#gmp-data-collection). It lets you globally monitor and alert on your workloads, without having to manually manage and operate Prometheus at scale [3](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus#gmp-system-overview).

Prometheus gives you monitoring by querying over 1,500 free metrics in Cloud Monitoring, including free GKE system metrics, using PromQL.

Managed Service for Prometheus facilitates monitoring and alerting on workloads and is responsible for creating and updating configurations based on PodMonitoring resources (objects) [4](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-managed#gmp-pod-monitoring).

The “gmp-system” namespace is part of the manifest file ‘operator.yaml’ [5](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/manifests#expandable-2) which is needed for the managed monitoring service for Prometheus.

I am thinking that you have enabled the Prometheus monitoring service, hence the “gmp-system” and “gmp-operator” were generated in your Workloads list in the Kubernetes engine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could not understand it much though. :( I provided more information under the ADDENDUM in my original question. I re-created an autopilot cluster. I unfortunately still have the problem. No clue why... Would you have any chance to look at the addendum I provided?